# Get Post Data Payload From Sent XHR

Tags: javascript

I am writing some code to intercept and log ever XHR request sent over JavaScript, but I am unable to find where to access the request payload from. Is this possible to do? My code is below, this logs the url, method, and response, but no payload.

```
let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (
  method,
  url,
  async,
  user,
  password
) {
  console.log("---hooked request---");
  console.log({ url });
  console.log({ method });
  console.log(this);

  this.addEventListener("load", function () {
    console.log("load: " + this.responseText);
  });

  return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
};
```